# Read grib2 file with xarray

Tags: python-2.7, python-xarray

I need to open a grib2 file with xarray. To do so, I'm using python 2.7 and pynio as engine in xarray:

```
grbs = xr.open_dataset('hrrr.t06z.wrfsubhf02.grib2'], engine = 'pynio')
```

Output:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                    (forecast_time0: 4, lv_HTGL0: 2, lv_HTGL1: 2, xgrid_0: 1799, ygrid_0: 1059)
Coordinates:
  * forecast_time0             (forecast_time0) timedelta64[ns] 5 days 15:00:00 ...
  * lv_HTGL1                   (lv_HTGL1) float32 1000.0 4000.0
  * lv_HTGL0                   (lv_HTGL0) float32 10.0 80.0
    gridlat_0                  (ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float32 21.1381 21.1451 ...
    gridlon_0                  (ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float32 -122.72 -122.693 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: xgrid_0, ygrid_0
Data variables:
    ULWRF_P0_L1_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 446.3 ...
    WIND_P8_L103_GLC0_avg5min  (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 5.31 ...
    SBT124_P0_L8_GLC0          (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 288.7 ...
    VDDSF_P0_L1_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.0 ...
    VIS_P0_L1_GLC0             (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 8.4e+03 ...
    DSWRF_P0_L1_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.0 ...
    CICEP_P0_L1_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.0 ...
    DLWRF_P0_L1_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 429.7 ...
    USWRF_P0_L1_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.0 ...
    ULWRF_P0_L8_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 291.0 ...
    HGT_P0_L3_GLC0             (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 1.4e+03 ...
    VGRD_P8_L103_GLC0_avg5min  (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 -4.92 ...
    gridrot_0                  (ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float32 -0.274008 ...
    VIL_P0_L10_GLC0            (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.0048 ...
    CSNOW_P0_L1_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.0 ...
    SBT123_P0_L8_GLC0          (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 251.5 ...
    GUST_P0_L1_GLC0            (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 6.469 ...
    SBT114_P0_L8_GLC0          (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 289.4 ...
    DPT_P0_L103_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 295.8 ...
    UGRD_P8_L103_GLC0_avg5min  (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 -2.02 ...
    RETOP_P0_L3_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 -999.0 ...
    REFD_P0_L103_GLC0          (forecast_time0, lv_HTGL1, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 -10.0 ...
    TMP_P0_L103_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 297.0 ...
    UGRD_P0_L103_GLC0          (forecast_time0, lv_HTGL0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 -1.998 ...
    HGT_P0_L215_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 461.2 ...
    UPHL_P0_2L103_GLC0         (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.0 ...
    SBT113_P0_L8_GLC0          (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 253.9 ...
    VBDSF_P0_L1_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.0 ...
    PRATE_P0_L1_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.0 ...
    CFRZR_P0_L1_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.0 ...
    CPOFP_P0_L1_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 -50.0 ...
    CRAIN_P0_L1_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.0 ...
    REFC_P0_L10_GLC0           (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 1.0 ...
    DSWRF_P8_L1_GLC0_avg15min  (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.0 ...
    VBDSF_P8_L1_GLC0_avg15min  (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.0 ...
    PRES_P0_L1_GLC0            (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 1.014e+05 ...
    SPFH_P0_L103_GLC0          (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 0.01705 ...
    VGRD_P0_L103_GLC0          (forecast_time0, lv_HTGL0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 -4.939 ...
    HGT_P0_L2_GLC0             (forecast_time0, ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float64 869.5 ...
```

I can load the file and see it's contents, I can also read the data of a given variable with slice method:

```
   data = grbs['DSWRF_P8_L1_GLC0_avg15min'].isel(**{'forecast_time0': 0}).sel(**{'ygrid_0': slice(22,24), 'xgrid_0': slice(-115,-110)})
```

Output:

```
0}).sel(**{'ygrid_0': slice(22,24), 'xgrid_0': slice(-115,-110)}) 
<xarray.DataArray 'DSWRF_P8_L1_GLC0_avg15min' (ygrid_0: 2, xgrid_0: 5)>
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
Coordinates:
    forecast_time0  timedelta64[ns] 5 days 15:00:00
    gridlat_0       (ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float32 22.4459 22.4396 22.4334 ...
    gridlon_0       (ygrid_0, xgrid_0) float32 -75.2096 -75.1823 -75.155 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: ygrid_0, xgrid_0
Attributes:
    production_status:                              Operational products
    center:                                         US National Weather Servi...
    level:                                          [ 0.]
    type_of_statistical_processing:                 Average
    long_name:                                      Downward short-wave radia...
    parameter_template_discipline_category_number:  [8 0 4 7]
    initial_time:                                   09/06/2017 (06:00)
    grid_type:                                      Lambert Conformal can be ...
    units:                                          W m-2
    statistical_process_duration:                   15 minutes (ending at for...
    level_type:                                     Ground or water surface
    parameter_discipline_and_category:              Meteorological products, ...
```

Now I would like to use the interpolation='nearest' method to retrieve the value of a given variable near a given latitude/longitude:

```
   data = grbs['DSWRF_P8_L1_GLC0_avg15min'].sel(gridlon_0=-75.2096, gridlat_0=22.4396, method='nearest')
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-0c24d2bdb040> in <module>()
      7 #data = grbs['DSWRF_P8_L1_GLC0_avg15min'].sel(gridlon_0=-75.2096, gridlat_0=22.4396, method='nearest') # ValueError: dimensions or multi-index levels ['gridlat_0', 'gridlon_0'] do not exist
      8 #data = grbs['DSWRF_P8_L1_GLC0_avg15min'].sel(lat=gridlat_0, lon = gridlon_0) # ValueError: dimensions or multi-index levels ['gridlat_0', 'gridlon_0'] do not exist
----> 9 data = grbs['DSWRF_P8_L1_GLC0_avg15min'].sel(gridlon_0=-75.2096, gridlat_0=22.4396, method='nearest')

/Users/maurice/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.pyc in sel(self, method, tolerance, drop, **indexers)
    690         """
    691         pos_indexers, new_indexes = indexing.remap_label_indexers(
--> 692             self, indexers, method=method, tolerance=tolerance
    693         )
    694         result = self.isel(drop=drop, **pos_indexers)

/Users/maurice/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.pyc in remap_label_indexers(data_obj, indexers, method, tolerance)
    275     new_indexes = {}
    276 
--> 277     dim_indexers = get_dim_indexers(data_obj, indexers)
    278     for dim, label in iteritems(dim_indexers):
    279         try:

/Users/maurice/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.pyc in get_dim_indexers(data_obj, indexers)
    243     if invalid:
    244         raise ValueError("dimensions or multi-index levels %r do not exist"
--> 245                          % invalid)
    246 
    247     level_indexers = defaultdict(dict)

ValueError: dimensions or multi-index levels ['gridlat_0', 'gridlon_0'] do not exist
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Note: The files can be found at http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hrrr/prod/ then the links with format hrrr.YYYMMDD/hrrr.tHHz.wrfsubhf**.grib2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lat/lon coordinate variables are 2-dimensional. A nearest neighbor lookup like this is not currently possible with xarray. The xarray developers are actively discussing  how this may be included in the package but nothing concrete has materialized yet. This github issue is quite relevant: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/475.